# why im getting a 4D array for my LSTM Training?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to train multiple csv File with LSTM. But before that, I was trying to reshape my csv files, so that I have a 3 dimensional array. Because with a 3 dimensional array, because LSTM layer accepts a 3D array as input which has a shape of `(n_sample, n_timesteps, n_features). . How can I do that? Ive tried something but why I'm getting a 4D Array?

I have set up my folder structure as follows. First, the main folder `data` is accessed. In the folder `data` there are several subfolders which are labelled with a name, e.g. `Hi`, `Thank you` etc. In each of these subfolders there are 5 CSV files.

```
   class    timestamp      x1            y554      z554
0    HI         0       0.620910  ...  0.764443 -0.000033 
1    HI         1       0.622164  ...  0.765593 -0.000033 
2    HI         2       0.615317  ...  0.763167 -0.000045 
3    HI         3       0.613590  ...  0.762744 -0.000032  
4    HI         4       0.615641  ...  0.765141 -0.000025 
...
[30 rows x 1664 columns]
```

Comment: Are "sequenceses" and "sequences" intended to be the same variable?

Comment: @MarkLavin - no Ive adjusted it into seq.

Comment: Each ot sequenceses contains a 1D array, so when you do a `np.array` you implicitly capture that structure as well. You might need to remove the window and directly append the df.